# Eclipse Luna not start

Tags: java, eclipse

until yesterday I was using the Eclipse Moon smoothly, but now will not start.
The initial part of the error messages recorded in the log is:

```
    !SESSION 2015-01-11 21:04:53.605 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-11 21:05:06.042
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred getting the bundle manifest.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.BundleInfo$Generation.getRawHeaders(BundleInfo.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.BundleInfo$CachedManifest.get(BundleInfo.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.BundleInfo$CachedManifest.get(BundleInfo.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.SupplementerRegistry.addSupplementer(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.startActivator(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.startExtensionActivators(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.initWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: An error occurred while reading the manifest file.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.Headers.parseManifest(Headers.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.BundleInfo$Generation.getRawHeaders(BundleInfo.java:109)
    ... 29 more
```

thank you in advance for your kind attention, and hope you can give me some help.

A hug for everyone.

Comment: this does not solve your problem, but maybe it is easier to download eclipse again and unpack it into a another folder and try to start your project or import it again ?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse for work. I strongly recommend using the long term support version, which is Juno 4.2 at https://eclipse.org/juno

Comment: To mark a question as solved, you should just click on the ✓ check mark to the left of the answer that solved your question, even if it is your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have deleted the **eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi** folder in eclipse installation, and works fine!

Thank you for your kind attention.

A hug for everyone.

Gustavo Echenique

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to install eclipse neon today and just ran a `sudo chmod -R 777 .` from the eclipse install directory and then the installer started.